# silverlight accordion control

Tags: silverlight-3.0

hoe can i enable scroll bars in accordion control of silverlight? I am using accordin control as menu if I am having so many accordion items i want to display with vertical scrolls bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use scrollviewer in silverlight